# PHP Version on Mac loads wrong mcrypt library when starting Artisan (Laravel App)

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt

When I try to start Artisan to run my larval App with

```
PHP Artisan
```

I get the following message in the terminal

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.25/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.25/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

As you see it tries to open the file directory "/php53.mcrypt" which is wrong in itself, because I only have "/php55-mcrypt" there.

Any ideas on how I can change this so it loads the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit php.ini file and edit reference:

```
sudo vi /private/etc/php.ini
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Finally, restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```